# Keeps reloading the content

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I seem to have a problem using the `$.ajax()` function to load content into a DIV from another page. It keeps reloading the content into the element.

As you can see from my debugger, the element `.driving_action_body` keeps reloading infinite (hence it's pulsing purple)

[image]

This is my code:

```
$('#drivingActions').on("show.bs.modal",function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $modal = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/project/?i=drivingActions&action="+action,
            data: {shipment_id,reference}, //If we need to pass any data, do so here.
            success: function(data) {
                $modal.find('.driving_action_body').html(data)
            }
        });

});
```

What am I doing wrong? I can load the content into the element, however it keeps "refreshing" infinite, causing the loaded page to not work correct.

**Update:**
If I use `.append()` instead of `.html()`, it does not keep refreshing the content:

```
success: function(data) {
    $modal.find('.driving_action_body').append(data)
}
```

However, I would like to use `.html()`, since append messes up the content.

Comment: Something must be triggering the `show.bs.modal` event again.

Comment: This "url" may be  url: "/project/index.php?i=drivingActions&action="+action, ?

Comment: What event is 'show.bs.modal'? You use 'preventDefault()' on the 'event' variable --> altough you only have 'e'. Fix this and try again.

Comment: @Sandrooco It's part of Bootstrap.

Comment: Just an update - it doesn't keep reloading the content, if I use append(data) instead of html(data). Updating my question.

Comment: According to your update: Update your html structure so you can simply append to a container. This will be the better solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#drivingActions').on("show.bs.modal",function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $modal = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/project/?i=drivingActions&action="+action,
            data: {shipment_id,reference}, //If we need to pass any data, do so here.
            success: function(data) {
                $modal.find('.driving_action_body').html(data);
                window.stop();// you need this
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: You should use snippet only if it actually works. Otherwise, just format it as code. Also, provide some explanation, not just code to make your answer awesome.